# Error while type casting pointer to structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
struct ll
{
    int data;
    struct ll *next;
};

struct ll *ptr,*root;
root = (struct ll *)malloc(sizeof(struct ll)); /* This line */

if(root == NULL)
{
    printf("FAILURE");
    exit(0);
}


root = NULL;
ptr = NULL;
```

Above code is written to declare and initialize pointers to a structure *ll* which is a linked list .
The line which is written in bold shows the following warnings during compilation:
**data definition has no type or storage class[enabled by default]****,**
**type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'root'**

Comment: (struct ll *)malloc(sizeof(struct ll));** is this is compile error?

Comment: Disregarding the actual problem, calling something `ll` is one of the ten signs you hate the maintainer of your code... =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allowed to have *statements* (except declarations) outside of any function in C. 
Since you haven't specified a *type* for `root`, the error message says that the type of `root` defaults to `int`. Obviously this is not what want.

Put your code inside a function (`main()` for example) and compile.

Additionally,

1) Don't cast the result of `malloc()` as it's [useless and error-prone.](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html)
2) You have losing the allocated pointer (with `malloc()`) as you are assigning `NULL` immediately after. But I am not sure what exactly you intend to do with it.
3) Include headers for the library functions you use (`<stdlib.h>` for `malloc` and `exit`)

Comment: In C, a declaration is not a statement (C++ is different here).